# How can I add text and images in listview which is in fragment

Tags: android

My chat.java class extends Fragment, and inflate chat.xml in which listview is made.

But now I want to add images and text in this listview using chatitemlist.xml

How can I do this?

Entire code here:

```
public class Chat extends Fragment {

    Context Chat;
    ArrayList<ChatItems> listt;
    ListView list;
    String[] names = { "Ram", "Abhi", "Rohit", "Holly", "James", "Hana", "Jack" };
    Integer[] imageId = { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,

    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ChatListAdapter customAdapter = new ChatListAdapter(getActivity()
                .getBaseContext(), R.layout.chatlistitems, listt);// data is
                                                                    // Dataitem
                                                                    // list
        list.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

and model class:

```
public class ChatItems {

    String text;
    int imageID;
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
    public int getImageID() {
        return imageID;
    }
    public void setImageID(int imageID) {
        this.imageID = imageID;
    }
}
```

and ChatListAdapter class::

```
public class ChatListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ChatItems> {



    ArrayList<ChatItems> dataitems;
    Context context;

    public ChatListAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
            ArrayList<Photo> items) {
        super(context, resourceId);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /* private view holder class */
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        ChatItems rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chatlistitems, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.names);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageID());
        holder.textView.setText(rowItem.getText());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by saving the text and image? You mean,, you wanna load them later without a network call or sth ?

Comment: i meant to add text and images

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an adapter and pass it your chat_list_item.xml as a view for single listView row.

Check out [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) tutorial, it should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DataItem Class

```
public class DataItem()
{
String text;
int imageID;
//Add getters ,setters
}
```

Create a `CustomAdpater` Which extends `ArrayAdpater<DataItem>`

```
public class CustomAdpater extends ArrayAdapter<DataItem> {

    Context context;

    public CustomAdpater(Context context, int resourceId,
            ArrayList<Photo> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
       TextView textView;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        DataItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.textView= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


        holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageID());
       holder.textView.setText(rowItem.getText());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Then call it in your Fragment

```
CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),R.layout.list_item,data);//data is Dataitem list
listview.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Comment: its is `ArrayList<DataItem> data` which has your text and image values to be displayed in List